# Looking for example of chained function in a module using .then for data validation and then database saves

Tags: node.js, express

Looking to find a clear and complete example of a case where async is used to handle chained function steps.  I have psuedo code below showing intent, but not certain if there is an example out there that would show; clearly, the actual code needed to call multiple steps from within the async function.

The function is using a basic async wrapper.

```
getUserById: asyncHandler ( (req, res, next) => {

    validateUser();
    SavetoDB();

    res.json({"message": "TBD...success"});
})
```

Comment: does your `validateUser` and `SavetoDB` return promise?

Comment: That is what I am delving into.  Save should. Valid may not need it.

Currently considering something like this:

(async () => {

  await validateUser();
  await SavetoDB();
  console.log('done!');

})();

Comment: Ok then, does `validateUser` do some asynchronous task or does is run synchronously?

Comment: It is just going to return valid or error. What would you recommend?

Comment: If `validateUser` runs synchronously, just awaiting `SavetoDB` should be fine. It would be helpful to know what `validateUser` is

Comment: validate User is "undesigned" at this moment. I am working on identifying a tangible approach to constructing modules with error control and routes.  Ultimately, this would probably vet required fields though. Thats for you help!!

Comment: if `asyncHandler` is the npm `express-async-handler`, you would need to make your `validateUser` return a promise as well if you doing some async task

Comment: So, then everything in the main function needs to return a promise. Correct? Easy enough...is that a bad practice?

Comment: `is that a bad practice?` not necessarily, `promise` was designed to do exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question isn't very well-formed.

Your SaveToDB() method will probably do some database task, which will be async. So you'll want to return a promise. So SaveToDB() could be something like :

```
exports.submitPost = async () => {

const data = await fetch('/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    field: {
      txt: this.state.newfield
    }
  })
})
const jsonData = await data.json();
return jsonData;
}
```

Then you can call is with .then:

```
submitPost().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Yes, I know. Hard to know exact;y what to ask when you are new to this stuff.  I think some of the code you provide is handled by the async middleware.   

What I am trying to get my head around is how to consecutively call the two internals:

validateUser();
SavetoDB();

Comment: I edited. Should be able to call each method consecutively without issue as long they return promises.

Comment: Many thanks! I am looking into some code posted above in the question responses. Your mod is appreciated!

Comment: @Seeker No problem. Please mark as the solution or upvote if it works out for you!